# Postman Printing specific information from Response

Tags: postman

I'm using Postman's console to display the response of the API Call with console.log, I'm using the runner since I have a lot of iterations. However, a lot of information from the API response are giving me trouble, so I would like to do is to print with console.log specific information of the responseBody.

As test with  Postman, I'm using the following:

```
var body = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(JSON.stringify(body.data));
```

The response is:

> [{"device":"1BED7","time":1505320342,"data":"05b006bcac00000000000000","snr":"21.00","linkQuality":"AVERAGE","seqNumber":555,"rinfos":[{"tap":"A2A","delay":1.4,"lat":"53.0","lng":"2.0"},{"tap":"A2B","delay":0.5,"lat":"53.0","lng":"2.0"}]},{"device":"1CED7","time":1505277142,"data":"05b006bcac00000000000000","snr":"20.68","linkQuality":"AVERAGE","seqNumber":554,"rinfos":[{"tap":"A2C","delay":1.3,"lat":"53.0","lng":"2.0"},{"tap":"232","delay":1.9,"lat":"53.0","lng":"2.0"}]},{"device":"152C3","time":1505233937,"data":"05b006bcac00000000000000","snr":"19.14","linkQuality":"AVERAGE","seqNumber":553,"rinfos":[{"tap":"215","delay":2.4,"lat":"53.0","lng":"2.0"}]},{"device":"1BF81","time":1505190735,"data":"05b006bcac00000000000000","snr":"21.67","linkQuality":"AVERAGE","seqNumber":552,"rinfos":[{"tap":"1CC","delay":2.0,"lat":"53.0","lng":"2.0"},{"tap":"25A","delay":1.6,"lat":"53.0","lng":"2.0"}]},

What I would want to print with console.log would be only the values of device, time and data:

> {"1BED7",1505320342,"05b006bcac00000000000000"},{"1CED7",1505277142,"05b006bcac00000000000000"},{"152C3",1505233937,"05b006bcac00000000000000"},
>   and so on...

My programming skills are very limited so sorry if the answer is so obvious, I have tested a lot of things but I'm still stuck.

Thanks a lot if you can help

Comment: `console.log(body.data.device);` and so on for other values

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it doesn't work, when I use  
`console.log(body.data.device)`, I have "null" as a response in the console

Comment: Yeah.I see that now.at that time You were showing the image of your  console so i couldn't apprehend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  think your your response is  array of objects.It is already a json object.So firstly what  you are doing wrong is you don't need to  parse it.You can directly use it.Check this below code snippet at the end of the answer.I think this satisfies your need.I used the forEach function to iterate through the the response array and push value that you need into the empty array.This result array contains object in following format.you can access each property of each object of this array by javascript `.` operator.I think that is quite obvious to you.
    `[
  {
    "device": "1BED7",
    "time": 1505320342,
    "data": "05b006bcac00000000000000"
  },
  {
    "device": "1CED7",
    "time": 1505277142,
    "data": "05b006bcac00000000000000"
  },
  {
    "device": "152C3",
    "time": 1505233937,
    "data": "05b006bcac00000000000000"
  },
  {
    "device": "1BF81",
    "time": 1505190735,
    "data": "05b006bcac00000000000000"
  }
]`

```js
var responseBody=[{"device":"1BED7","time":1505320342,"data":"05b006bcac00000000000000","snr":"21.00","linkQuality":"AVERAGE","seqNumber":555,"rinfos":[{"tap":"A2A","delay":1.4,"lat":"53.0","lng":"2.0"},{"tap":"A2B","delay":0.5,"lat":"53.0","lng":"2.0"}]},
    {"device":"1CED7","time":1505277142,"data":"05b006bcac00000000000000","snr":"20.68","linkQuality":"AVERAGE","seqNumber":554,"rinfos":[{"tap":"A2C","delay":1.3,"lat":"53.0","lng":"2.0"},{"tap":"232","delay":1.9,"lat":"53.0","lng":"2.0"}]},{"device":"152C3","time":1505233937,"data":"05b006bcac00000000000000","snr":"19.14","linkQuality":"AVERAGE","seqNumber":553,"rinfos":[{"tap":"215","delay":2.4,"lat":"53.0","lng":"2.0"}]},{"device":"1BF81","time":1505190735,"data":"05b006bcac00000000000000","snr":"21.67","linkQuality":"AVERAGE","seqNumber":552,"rinfos":[{"tap":"1CC","delay":2.0,"lat":"53.0","lng":"2.0"},{"tap":"25A","delay":1.6,"lat":"53.0","lng":"2.0"}]}];
var array=[];
responseBody.forEach(function (obj) {
    array.push({device:obj.device,time:obj.time,data:obj.data})
})
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked!!! I see now exactly what I was doing wrong. Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

```
let results = _.map(JSON.parse(responseBody), 
  (sensor) => { return [sensor.device, sensor.time, sensor.data]});

// results contains an array like
// [[deviceId1, time1, data1], [deviceId1, time1, data1], ...]

console.log(results);
```